# kivy dropdown automatically dismissed

Tags: kivy

I want the dropdown list to stay visible after a selection is made (instead of disapearing). I have tried several syntax with the BooleanProperty dismiss_on_select but can't seem to figure it out. I am new to Python and Kivy.
Where and how can I set this property ? Thanks

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MultiSelectSpinner(Button):


    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)

    values = ListProperty([])
    """Values to choose from."""
    selected_values = ListProperty([])
    """List of values selected by the user."""


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.bind(dropdown=self.update_dropdown)
        self.bind(values=self.update_dropdown)
        super(MultiSelectSpinner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_release=self.toggle_dropdown)

    def toggle_dropdown(self, *args):
        if self.dropdown.parent:
            self.dropdown.dismiss()
        else:
            self.dropdown.open(self)

    def update_dropdown(self, *args):
        if not self.dropdown:
            self.dropdown = DropDown()
        values = self.values
        if values:
            if self.dropdown.children:
                self.dropdown.clear_widgets()
            for value in values:
                b = Factory.MultiSelectOption(text=value)
                b.bind(state=self.select_value)
                self.dropdown.add_widget(b)

    def select_value(self, instance, value):
        if value == 'down':
            if instance.text not in self.selected_values:
                self.selected_values.append(instance.text)
        else:
            if instance.text in self.selected_values:
                self.selected_values.remove(instance.text)

    def on_selected_values(self, instance, value):
        if value:
            self.text = ', '.join(value)
        else:
            self.text = ''

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Color selection'
        MultiSelectSpinner:
            id: color
            values: 'White','Black'

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'Shape selection'
        MultiSelectSpinner:
            id: shape
            values: 'Circle','Square'

<MultiSelectOption@ToggleButton>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: '60dp'
'''

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(kv))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DropDown` with `auto_dismiss=False` keyword, or edit in on the fly:

```
d = DropDown()
d.auto_dismiss = False
```

For future cases please check the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html#kivy.uix.dropdown.DropDown.auto_dismiss) before asking.

Comment: Even if I add these it still does not seem to work in my code :

Comment: def __init__(self, auto_dismiss=False, dismiss_on_select=False, **kwargs):
        super(MultiSelectSpinner, self).__init__(auto_dismiss=False, dismiss_on_select=False, **kwargs)
        self.bind(on_release=self.toggle_dropdown)
        
def toggle_dropdown(self, auto_dismiss=False, dismiss_on_select=False, *args):
 

    def update_dropdown(self, auto_dismiss=False, dismiss_on_select=False, *args):

Comment: @Hector Is `MultiSelectSpinner` a `DropDown`? No. Where is the `DropDown`? `self.dropdown = DropDown()`, therefore update _that_ object and not `__init__` of a random thing. :P

Answer (score 0):

**no need to use parent arg create a separate object something like that works like charm**

```
class CustDropDown(DropDown):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(CustDropDown, self).__init__()
        self.dismiss()
```

> and use anywhere you want

Comment: You could explain in detail how this answer's solution works versus how OP's attempt didn't work out as well.  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review due to you being a new contributor.  Your answer is much appreciated & helpful.  This comment is to help you take a good answer & make it excellent.